# Is it possible to completely suppress a css rule?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When customizing third party libs i try as much as possible to not block my upgrade options by editing source files directly.

So when it came to working with Twitter's Bootstrap web framework i wanted to "suppress" one of the css rules in the [bootstrap-responsive.css](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css) file.

> @media (min-width: 1200px) {...}

I have an override file but can't seem to "suppress" the rule by declaring an empty rule?

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

> @media (min-width: 1200px) {}

But it doesn't work.  Anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: What about simply removing it from the file?

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of that - wanted to know if it can be done or not

Comment: what you want is not possible. you can only override each and every rule, but that make no sense here.

just remove the not needed lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to "suppress" those styles you'll have to set the styles defined by Twitter Bootstrap to some other value.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) 
{
    ... reset each value to some default
}
```